# Bypassing Pine-Script's Security Calling Limit Issue

Tags: pine-script

I am using the following code for calculating daily range -

```
dailyHigh1  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D" , high[1],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
dailyLow1   = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D" , low [1],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
dayrange1 = dailyHigh1 - dailyLow1
```

This approach is limiting me from calling more periods of a security as tradingview limit is 40. If there is a way around it, possible to code it in one line, by calling only one security instead of two, please let me know.

Thanks for your time. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can merge multiple items that you want for one timeframe

```
[dailyHigh1  ,dailyLow1]=request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D" , [high[1],low[1]],lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
```